# running snap-applications within firejail

Tags: lubuntu, snap

I found out that my current version of **firejail** (sandboxing-programme), which is *0.9.52-1 amd64*, lists among so many other profiles the **snap.profile** (in /etc/firejail).
I have **snap** installed, and the following commands work well:

```
firejail snap find sudoku
firejail snap install gnome-sudoku
firejail snap refresh
```

Yet the starting of installed programmes fails.

I tried the following:

`firejail –profile=/etc/firejail/snap.profile /snap/bin/gnome-sudoku`

Yet it wouldn´t start. I get the message:

```
Reading profile /etc/firejail/snap.profile
Reading profile /etc/firejail/disable-common.inc
Reading profile /etc/firejail/disable-passwdmgr.inc
Reading profile /etc/firejail/disable-programs.inc
Reading profile /etc/firejail/whitelist-common.inc
Parent pid 9293, child pid 9294
Child process initialized in 38.71 ms
cannot execute snap-update-ns: Permission denied
snap-update-ns failed with code 1: No such file or directory

Parent is shutting down, bye…
```

Is there any solution to this?

My system:
Linux/Lubuntu 16.04.4 LTS, 64 bit

Comment: I don't think it's recommended that you attempt this, snappy has [sandboxing out-of-the-box](https://snapdocs.labix.org/security-policy-and-sandboxing/554) as it were.

Comment: Hi. Tnx for the link. O.K., I understand that snaps have some kind of sandboxing-mechanism. What I don´t get is why there is a snap-profile at all (which is provided by firejail, see https://github.com/netblue30/firejail/blob/master/etc/snap.profile). The mere existence of that profile led me to believe it could be applied to snaps. But perhaps it´s just for the maintenance of snaps???  `firejail snap find [package-name],   
firejail snap install  [package-name],      
firejail snap refresh`